# link to a external cmd

Tags: external-calls

I have started a process `process=StartProcess["cmd"];`

```
outputFile="C:\\Users\\atfai\\Desktop\\Version Control System\\output.txt";
run[commands_]:=Module[{},
    WriteLine[process,commands<>" >> \""<>outputFile<>"\""];Import[outputFile]
];
```

I am able to successfully send any command and get results from it. But i would like to view the `cmd` in a separate window.

If i use `cmd=LinkLaunch["C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"]`. `cmd` opens in a separate window but i can't send any commands to it. I used the following:
`WriteLine[cmd, commands]`.

Is there a way to see the process in a separate window or if not then how do i send command to the `LinkObject` connected with `cmd`?

Urgent help needed!

Comment: That's not what `LinkLaunch` is for.  If you are not dealing with MathLink/WSTP (or do not know what those are), do not use `LinkLaunch`. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html

Comment: so is there a way for ProcessObject to link to a currently running process or process started by StartProcess to be started in a new window externally?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think so (at least on Windows).  If you make it run in a window, you forfeit the ability to pass input to it and read output from it.  If you have a window, that window will have keyboard input.

Comment: Some hackery with [splitting pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) may be possible, and more likely to be achievable on Unix